# Problem with color tables when there are nested tabulars

Tags: tables, color, nesting

Color tables work great when using within a single tabular environment. However, when using it within nested tabular environments, a rowcolor command spans the whole nested table instead of a single row within the nexted table. This is show in the following sample file

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} EmpID & FirstName & LastName & Title \\\hline
e1 & John & Smith & Mr. \\
e2 & Mary & Heart & Mrs. \\
e3 & Juan & Guerra & Mr. \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{3mm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} ProductKey & TimeKey & Quantity \\\hline
p2 & t2 & 100 \\
p3 & t3 & 100 \\
p4 & t4 & 100 \\
p5 & t5 & 100 \\
p6 & t6 & 100 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} EmpID & FirstName & LastName & Title \\\hline
e1 & John & Smith & Mr. \\
e2 & Mary & Heart & Mrs. \\
e3 & Juan & Guerra & Mr. \\\hline
\end{tabular}
& &
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} ProductKey & TimeKey & Quantity \\\hline
p2 & t2 & 100 \\
p3 & t3 & 100 \\
p4 & t4 & 100 \\
p5 & t5 & 100 \\
p6 & t6 & 100 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

When I compile it with pdflatex using MikTeX I obtain the following output

[image: problem with rowcolor in nested tabular]

Answer (score 2):

use instead `\cellcolor[black]{0.8}` for every column in that line:

```
\cellcolor[black]{0.8} EmpID & \cellcolor[black]{0.8}FirstName & \cellcolor[black]{0.8}LastName & \cellcolor[black]{0.8}Title \\\hline
```

*or* write in the following tabular row

```
\rowcolor{white}
```

*or* (my preferred solution) use package `xcolor` and the command `\hiderowcolors`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} EmpID & FirstName & LastName & Title \\\hline
\hiderowcolors
e1 & John & Smith & Mr. \\
e2 & Mary & Heart & Mrs. \\
e3 & Juan & Guerra & Mr. \\\hline
\end{tabular}
& &
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} ProductKey & TimeKey & Quantity \\\hline
\hiderowcolors
p2 & t2 & 100 \\
p3 & t3 & 100 \\
p4 & t4 & 100 \\
p5 & t5 & 100 \\
p6 & t6 & 100 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your problem, it compiles fine here:

[image]

Output of `\listfiles`:

> ```
>  *File List*
>   report.cls    2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
>   size10.clo    2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option)
> colortbl.sty    2001/02/13 v0.1j Color table columns (DPC)
>    array.sty    2005/08/23 v2.4b Tabular extension package (FMi)
>    color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
>    color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
>   pdftex.def    2007/01/08 v0.04d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
>  ***********
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` in the nested tabulars (with the key `colortbl-like`), you will have the expected output (`nicematrix` has its own system to color rows, cells and columns based on PGF/Tikz).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} EmpID & FirstName & LastName & Title \\\hline
e1 & John & Smith & Mr. \\
e2 & Mary & Heart & Mrs. \\
e3 & Juan & Guerra & Mr. \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{3mm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} ProductKey & TimeKey & Quantity \\\hline
p2 & t2 & 100 \\
p3 & t3 & 100 \\
p4 & t4 & 100 \\
p5 & t5 & 100 \\
p6 & t6 & 100 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{NiceTabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}[colortbl-like]\Hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} EmpID & FirstName & LastName & Title \\\Hline
e1 & John & Smith & Mr. \\
e2 & Mary & Heart & Mrs. \\
e3 & Juan & Guerra & Mr. \\\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
& &
\begin{NiceTabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}[colortbl-like]\Hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} ProductKey & TimeKey & Quantity \\\Hline
p2 & t2 & 100 \\
p3 & t3 & 100 \\
p4 & t4 & 100 \\
p5 & t5 & 100 \\
p6 & t6 & 100 \\\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]